# Can the Python interpreter and Python app source code be embedded into a compiled program?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want to put the Python interpreter and all the source files of a fairly large Python application with multiple .py files into an executable Linux file.

Thus when running the application, the Python interpreter will run the Python source code that is embedded into the executable.

Using Python 3.

Is such a thing possible?

Edit: in addition to the selected answer another option is to use Cython.

Comment: _"Possible"_ ? Yes. The real question is [how](https://docs.python.org/2/extending/embedding.html) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like you're looking for a packaging module, like [py2exe](http://www.py2exe.org/) or [cx_Freeze](http://cx-freeze.sourceforge.net/) (I prefer the latter). They bundle the interpreter and your files together so that a machine without an installation of Python can run your program.